# When using Keras categorical_crossentropy loss, should you use softmax on the last layer?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, keras, classification, softmax

Most examples I've seen implement softmax on the last layer. But I read that Keras `categorical_crossentropy` automatically applies softmax after the last layer so doing it is redundant and leads to reduced performance. Who is right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, Keras categorical_crossentropy does not apply softmax to the output (see the [categorical_crossentropy implementation](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/losses.py#L57) and the [Tensorflow backend call](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py#L2873)). However, if you use the backend function directly, there exists the option of setting `from_logits=True`.